# Getting Exception while using Timeline column as Hive Partition Field

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hive-partitions

I am trying to load data from normal table to Hive partitioned table.

Here is my normal table syntax:

```
create table x(name string, date1 string);
```

Here is my new partitioned table syntax:

```
create table y (name string, date1 string) partitioned by (timestamp1 string);
```

Here is how I am how to load data to y:

```
insert into table y PARTITION(SUBSTR(date1,0,2)) select name, date1 from x;
```

Here is my Exception:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:39 missing ) at '(' near ',' in column name
line 1:51 cannot recognize input near '0' ',' '2' in column name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic partitioning:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true; 
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert into table y PARTITION(timestamp1) 
select name, date1, SUBSTR(date1,0,2) as timestamp1  from x;
```